# What is the relationship between the u-coordinate and the x-coordinate, if v is constrained to be 0?

Tags: linear-transformations, mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems, transformational-geometry

> An x-y coordinate system is shown below. A second system, u-v, is also shown. What is the relationship between the u-coordinate and the x-coordinate, if v is constrained to be 0?

[image]

I tried projecting $x$ onto $u$ but am stuck at $u=cos(55) * x - c$ for the last hour.